# wav file writing and loading using cpp

Tags: c++, audio, wav

I have been working on a project based on a wav file with cpp. but no matter what i put in, I always get the output that's only the 1/2 size of the original input. I'm using the algorithm as following:
http://rogerchansdigitalworld.blogspot.com/2010/05/how-to-read-wav-format-file-in-c.html
http://ltheory.com/blog/writeWav.txt

anyone can give a hint?

my main function is:

```
int main()
{
    string filename = "U:\\workspace\\ECE420\\psola.github\\aa.wav";
    string directory;
    const size_t last_slash_idx = filename.rfind('\\');
    if (std::string::npos != last_slash_idx)
    {
        directory = filename.substr(0, last_slash_idx);
    }

    string filename1 = "U:\\workspace\\ECE420\\psola.github\\voiceprocessed.wav";
    string directory1;
    const size_t last_slash_idx1 = filename1.rfind('\\');
    if (std::string::npos != last_slash_idx1)
    {
        directory1 = filename1.substr(0, last_slash_idx1);
    }

    WavData song;
    int num = filename.size();
    char file_char[100];
    for (int a=0;a<=num;a++){
        file_char[a]=filename[a];
    }
    WavData song1;//

    int num1 = filename1.size();
        char file_char1[100];
        for (int a=0;a<=num1;a++){
            file_char1[a]=filename1[a];
        }


    loadWaveFile(file_char,&song);
    cout<<"there are "<<song.size/2<<" samples in this WAV file."<<endl;


   writeWAVData(file_char1, song.data, song.size, 44100, 1);
   cout<<"2,there are "<<song1.size/2<<" samples in this WAV file."<<endl;

   cout<<"success"<<endl;

    return 0;


        }
```

Comment: Well, you do divide `song.size` by 2 before printing it out... Also, there's no need to copy the file names into a `char` array; just use [`std::string::c_str()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/)

Comment: `size` field in `WavData` structure is number of samples (i.e. shorts), while `writeWAVData` expects number of bytes. You should adjust either read or write method.

Comment: Also `song1` is never initialized, so I have no idea what you expect to be printed with the second `cout`